# Почему запустить процесс, который только что выполнил I/O, повышает продуктивность ЦП?

Tags: unix, io, ос, cpu, процессор

Почему процессор запускает процесс, который только что выполнил I/O, а не переключается на следующий? 
Пытаюсь разобраться в принципах scheduling в ОС - и не понимаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно выполнение запроса на ввод/вывод  выглядит следующим образом:

1. Системный вызов read/write ().
2. Обработка оного на общем уровне/уровнях vfs.
3. Передача запроса драйверу конкретного устройства.
4. Посылка драйвером запроса на данные устройству (или ещё-кому) и усыпление процесса до получения ответа.
5. Пробуждение процесса (постановка в очередь выполнения) при ответе и возврат из системного вызова.
6. Дальнейшая обработка данных в пользовательском пространстве.

Таким образом если процесс не пробуждался бы после выполнения ввода-вывода, то он просто не мог бы обработать полученные данные и оставался бы вечно спящим, что в принципе не имеет никакого смысла...

#### Минутка terminology-nazi

> Почему процессор запускает процесс

На уровне, на котором можно говорить о работе «процессора» такой вещи, как абстракции «процесс» не существует, оная возникает только на уровне операционной системы.

> в принципах scheduling

В русской терминологии вполне устоялся такой термин, как «планировщик»